# How can I fix this repetitive code? - Android

Tags: android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);

    etColor1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etColor1);
    etColor1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            etColor1.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    btnEdit1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit1);
    btnEdit1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            etColor1.setEnabled(true);
            etColor1.requestFocus();
        }
    });

    etColor2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etColor2);
    etColor2.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            etColor2.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    btnEdit2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit2);
    btnEdit2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            etColor2.setEnabled(true);
            etColor2.requestFocus();
        }
    });

    etColor3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etColor3);
    etColor3.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            etColor3.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    btnEdit3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnEdit3);
    btnEdit3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            etColor3.setEnabled(true);
            etColor3.requestFocus();
        }
    });
```

Hi guys! So I have this code that detects Focus for EditText. Initially, all EditTexts are disabled and then when I click an 'Edit' button beside it, it will be focused (other EditTexts are still disable), and then when I click other 'Edit' button, the EditText that I have clicked already will be disabled again.

The code does what I want very well, but I believed it can be shorten. Sorry for the newb question. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Notice how you're not even making use of the argument(View v). Use that and it will simplify your code considerably. Also, you should note that an EditText and a Button in Android are both derived from View, so their instances can definitely be treated as Views.

Comment: Also, if you want to practice using Java, I'd recommend you use this site: http://codingbat.com/java

Comment: Thanks Sthepan. I will try what you recommend. I am a beginner, so thanks for that resources. Good Day my friend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Stephan mentioned, you can make use of the fact that the view you set the listener on is provided to you in the callback. Just make your Activity implement those interfaces, and you can simplify this quite a bit:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements 
        View.OnFocusChangeListener, View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstance);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);

        int[] editTexts = new int[] { R.id.etColor1, R.id.etColor2, R.id.etColor3 };
        for (int editText : editTexts) {
            findViewById(editText).setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        }

        int[] buttons = new int[] { R.id.btnEdit1, R.id.btnEdit2, R.id.btnEdit3 };
        for (int button : buttons) {
            findViewById(button).setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        v.setEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        v.setEnabled(true);
        v.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @kcoppock. Will try your code now! I am still learning so this is a helpful answer. Will try to analyze it as much as I can.